# None Js Exit code errro when i try to emulate app

Tags: android, node.js, macos, cordova, command-line-interface

When i try to emulate my cordova app,i am getting the following error:

> UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
>   (node:9254) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.

And the app doesnt emulate at all.I have set up Java,Node Js and Cordova via terminal.I am using mac.

These are my versions:
**Java**

> **java version "10.0.1" 2018-04-17
>   Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment 18.3 (build 10.0.1+10)
>   Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 18.3 (build 10.0.1+10, mixed mode)**

**Node**

> ***v9.11.1***

**Cordova**

> **8.0.0**

Ive already created a virtual device and its running.And i tried emulating the app as follows.Also i have already added the android platform:

```
cordova run --emulator
```

I have also tried building and running with gradle as depicted in the cordova guide:[Cordova Guide](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/dev/guide/platforms/android/index.html)

Comment: Is not related, i receive this warning too when build, but is only a Warning of deprecation. Please describe more of how not work.. Build are successfully completed?

Comment: The app doesnt emulate at all